# Initializing a class at Django startup and then referring to it in views

Tags: python, django

I am trying to do some pre-processing at Django startup (I put a startup script that runs once in urls.py) and then use the created instance of an object in my views.  How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the singleton design pattern.

Comment: I'm already doing that. I only have one instance of the object.  I'm trying to pass that object to views and I can't figure out how.

Comment: The singleton pattern is not "create one instance". It is "create one instance and retrieve it from any point in the code". Please check it out again, more carefully.

Comment: nevermind, i could just import urls module =/ sometimes i amaze myself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Context Processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#template-context-processors) to add it to your template context.

If you want it in the `View`, rather than the `Template`, then you can either have a base View class that has this, or just import the reference into the module your view is in (and access it directly).

Be aware that each django thread may have a different copy of the object in memory, so this should really only be used for read-only access. If you make changes to it, you are likely to find yourself in a world of hurt.